# Por que não aceitar perguntas sobre mercado de trabalho?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Eu fiz uma pergunta no site principal, mas ela foi suspensa por um moderador, que disse que perguntas sobre mercado de trabalho não eram aceitas, mas que isso poderia ser debatido aqui no meta. A pergunta era assim (a original eu excluí):

> sou recém formado e a vida me presenteou com uma oportunidade de trabalho como programador Java com frameworks Swing, tenho feito um curso de programação android na treinaweb e tem sido muito bom, o problema que para ser programador android existe muitas áreas de atuação, e gostaria de saber quais as áreas de atuação com desenvolvimento android que mais tem ganhado o mercado de trabalho. estou interessado em foca meus esforços para criar aplicativos corporativos, mas já ouvir falar que a área de games também é boa.

O que vocês acham de perguntas sobre esse tipo de assunto? Devem ser aceitas ou não?

Comment: Oi, eu de novo :) Funciona assim: o "beta" é o site principal, sobre programação (ele ainda está em fase beta). O "meta" é onde a gente discute o site. A pergunta sobre mercado de trabalho não está no escopo de nenhum dos dois, mas o fato de não estar no escopo do site principal pode ser debatido aqui no meta. Se a comunidade decidir aceitar perguntas sobre mercado de trabalho, a sua pergunta no site principal pode ser reaberta e respondida. Ficou mais claro agora? E posso editar esta sua pergunta e transformá-la num debate sobre aceitar perguntas sobre esse tema?

Comment: Bom, editei. Se quiser, pode editar ainda mais (tem um link para isso logo abaixo das tags na pergunta).

Comment: Só pra ajudar na discussão, o link de onde tem a votação desse assunto é esse aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1190/73

Answer (score 14):

Um dos motivos de não aceitar perguntas deste tipo é porque elas não tem uma resposta de verdade.

Algumas pessoas poderiam responder com suas opiniões, mas nada que seja objetivo. Provavelmente as respostas seriam diferentes para cada região e no decorrer do tempo.

Enfim, embora conselhos gerais e discussões possam ajudar quem está começando, o conteúdo não é adequado ao formato do site. Para isso seria interessante usar algum fórum de desenvolvimento.

Mas fique à vontade para criar perguntas sobre dúvidas específicas de programação.

Comment: Respeitosamente discordo. Acredito que se não fosse possível ter respostas baseadas em fatos sobre o tema mencionado não existiria o workplace.stackexchange.com. Me lembro que foram mencionadas algumas vezes pelo Gabe que perguntas relacionadas a Dev. mas que não fossem diretamente ligadas a programação poderia ser toleradas, neste caso, do meu ponto de vista isso seria interessante, visto que não temos um Workplace em PT, e certamente perguntar lá não seria válido para alguém no Brasil (talvez para alguém em Portugal...). Mas... Já sei o que vai acontecer... :)

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade Eu acompanho o Workplace há mais de um ano. Realmente existem coisas boas lá, embora muitas delas sejam confusas quanto à validade em cada região. Mas note que cada site define um escopo e as regras para as perguntas que vai aceitar. Alguns são mais flexíveis que outros. Note ainda que "workplace" é sobre ambiente de trabalho, não sobre "mercado de trabalho". Além disso, [eu também concordo que este é um assunto interessante](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272/227)! Mas também creio que traria muito ruído e conteúdo de baixa qualidade para o escopo do SO.

Comment: Concordo quando você diz que trairia muito ruído e conteúdo de baixa qualidade. Olhando por este lado talvez seja interessante mesmo evitar esse tipo de conteúdo por enquanto...

Comment: A variação temporal é algo que ocorre com todas as questões (inclusive as técnicas). Tudo evolui. O argumento da variação espacial é a mais preocupante... ainda mais em se tratando desse assunto.

Comment: Creio que o principal motivo (descrito pelo utluiz) é, de fato, a ausência de uma resposta verdadeira, no sentido de que qualquer resposta seria subjetiva, baseada na opinião de quem está escrevendo.